# no variable value in django url when append data using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am getting json data and parsing using jquery.

```
$.each(data, function(i, v) {
  var html = '<p class="is-marginless"><a href="{% url "phone" slug="' + v.slug + '" location="pakistan" %}">' + v.model + '</a></p>'
  $('#search').append(html);
});
```

but I am getting this url when rendered

```
http://localhost:8000/'%20+%20v.slug%20+%20'-price-in-pakistan/
```

I have tried so many varients but with no luck. I am not getting value from v.slug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{% url %}` template tag is parsed and executed on your back-end by Django, *before* the HTML page is sent to your browser. Look at the source of the javascript in your browser developer tools (to see what your actual executed javascript looks like) and you'll see that your javascript looks like this:

```
$.each(data, function(i, v) {
   var html = '<p class="is-marginless"><a href="http://localhost:8000/%20+%20v.slug%20+%20-price-in-pakistan/">' + v.model + '</a></p>'
   $('#search').append(html);
});
```

So you can't use the `{% url %} reversal template tag inside your javascript, you need to construct your URL differently. There's a few ways to do this:

- Hard code the parts of the URL path, getting the protocol and host using js from the current URL of the page (using `window.location.protocol` and `window.location.host`)
- Create a javascript `var` in your template with as a prototype, then replacing the slug part with `v.slug` in your javascript, e.g. `var urlPrototype = '{% url "phone" slug="prototype-slug" location="pakistan" %}'`. This is cleaner as it allows you to change the URL later without breaking things.
- Have the ajax response return the URL as a variable instead of the slug (`v.url`). Your view can construct the URL using `reverse("photo", kwargs={'slug': slug, 'location': 'pakistan'})` and then your script parsing the response can just use the `v.url` variable.